# Can I programmatically determine from a WPF app which Virtual COM ports are incoming and which are outgoing?

Tags: c#, wpf, bluetooth, serial-port, virtual-serial-port

I have a Bluetooth serial device I need to connect to. I can query the WMI data base to find the Bluetooth ports that I need by using

```
Get-WmiObject -query "select DeviceID,PNPDeviceID from Win32_SerialPort"
```

or using the registry by inspecting

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM\Device\BthModem0`

however I can't find an exposed API that allows me to determine which of the two created Virtual COM ports are incoming and outgoing.

This information is displayed by Windows if you dig deep enough in the Device Manager and so I should be available (by a PInvoke or something?) but I need to find out a way to find it programatically from a WPF application.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is to get the device capabilities.

Note the difference: Incoming Ports are
[image: Incoming vs Outgoing Port Capabilities]

I have created a sample C++ sample that does what you need based on the following [example](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/259695). You will need to use PINVOKE to call the appropriate methods. I am sorry I cannot provide the C# code as its for my work.

This depends on the Microsoft Bluetooth stack. You will need some modifications for widcomm or the Toshiba Bluetooth stack.

**You can fetch the sample from [Github](https://github.com/leramirez55/Win32BluetoothSerialEnumeration)**

To get it to work you will need to add the following to the linker options

Setupapi.lib
Ole32.lib

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <setupapi.h>
#include <devguid.h>
#include <regstr.h>
#include "Objbase.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    HDEVINFO hDevInfo;
    SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData;
    DWORD i;
    CLSID guid;
    //Class = Ports
    //ClassGuid = { 4d36e978 - e325 - 11ce - bfc1 - 08002be10318}


    LPCOLESTR  guidString = L"{86E0D1E0-8089-11D0-9CE4-08003E301F73}";
    HRESULT a = CLSIDFromString(guidString, &guid);
    // Create a HDEVINFO with all present devices.
    hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&guid,
        0, // Enumerator
        0,
        DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);

    if (hDevInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        // Insert error handling here.
        return 1;
    }

    // Enumerate through all devices in Set.

    DeviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);
    for (i = 0;SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo, i,
        &DeviceInfoData);i++)
    {
        DWORD DataT;
        LPTSTR buffer = (LPTSTR)LocalAlloc(LPTR, 4096 * 2);
        DWORD buffersize = 4096;

        LPBYTE buffer2 = (LPBYTE)LocalAlloc(LPTR, 4096 * 2);



        SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
            hDevInfo,
            &DeviceInfoData,
            SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME,
            &DataT,
            (PBYTE)buffer,
            buffersize,
            &buffersize);





        if (wcsstr(buffer, L"Standard Serial over Bluetooth link"))
        {
            SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
                hDevInfo,
                &DeviceInfoData,
                SPDRP_CAPABILITIES,
                &DataT,
                (PBYTE)buffer2,
                buffersize,
                &buffersize);

            wprintf(L"Result:%s - ", buffer);
            int a = *buffer2;
            if (a == 0xC0)
            {
                wprintf(L"Incoming");
            }
            else if (a == 0xC4)
            {
                wprintf(L"Outgoing");
            }

            wprintf(L"\n", buffer);

        }

        if (buffer) LocalFree(buffer);
    }


    if (GetLastError() != NO_ERROR &&
        GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
    {
        // Insert error handling here.
        return 1;
    }

    //  Cleanup
    SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I know you said that you can't share the C# code because it is your work's. Unfortunately that means this is not really an answer for the OP. Maybe you could provide some hints on _how_ to interop with native code from C#? That would be more helpful for future readers.

Comment: It looks like the OP has 3 questions:

1. How can I tell the difference between a outgoing and incoming port.
2. What API can be used to find that difference 
3. Can it be done from WPF ( .net  )

The problem is I don't know what is the best way to give a PINVOKE sample.

Comment: Fair enough. I was just looking for more of a relation to C# integration. Thanks for the good C++.

Comment: Should I just wrap this as a function and use the dll from C# with the C++ code returning a json or xml string? That would literally just provide a full code solution the question but requires an extra step of managing a C++ project

Comment: I believe that I answered all Three. 1. I answered which device capability to look at. 2. I answered which native API to use by providing a native example. 3. I let the OP know that PINVOKING these methods in this order would let him get the result he needed. 

I guess we can just wait for the OP to chime in.

Comment: @Luis thanks, I have read the reply and really appreciate the work - I am waiting to get back into work on Monday before I can try it out. I have not done much PInvoke before but I've starred a couple of SO Q's that describe two methods 1: Wrapping a C++ object into a .NET .dll or 2: Invoking an ordinary (non .NET) .dll. I was a bit concerned about using native code since I gather there are issues with 32-bit and 64-bit? e.g. if I compile for my Windows 10 64 bit platform, the .dll won't run on a 32bit Vista for example ..

Comment: @Luis Also I should add that it working across the BT stacks is important so I need to test first - our test systems are Broadcomm and Microsoft and so I will be able to check that when I get back on Monday. However Widcom and Toshiba will also have to be supported, do you have any inkling on whether the `0xC0 = Incoming` and `0xC4 = Outgoing` is a specification or just something that you noticed worked with the MS stack that differentiates incoming and outgoing? I ask because it might be a bit flag that is combined with other flags in which case checking for equality is not the way to go ...

Comment: @Brendan 

In retrospect it will probably be less code to just write the native code and compile it for 32 and 64 bit targets and call it from C#. However you will forever have to manage that extra project. It really depends on you. Even if you use PINVOKE some functions will require that you have wrappers that check the platform before you call them

Comment: @Brendan You are correct about the flags you should only be checking the CM_DEVCAP_REMOVABLE flag. The outgoing port is the one used to make connections from the PC to the device as such when its created it requires that its attached to a device and so its removable. Incoming ports don't have such restrictions you can create them from the UI at will. If you really want you can also use the "Bus Reported Device Description" as its attached to the outgoing port but the code is a little bit trickier to write. In addition this string depends on the firmware and so may vary from device to device.

Comment: @Brendan Can send or post some images of the properties for the device that you are trying to support  on both the widcomm stack and the Toshiba stack? Additionally be carefull when uninstalling the widcomm stack. There are reports as recent as this year, that it could potentially wipe the drive due to an unknown [issue](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/widcomm-uninstalltion-wipes-out-the-computer-new/ffe5f236-da04-4c3c-8df9-696080ec9d0c?page=10).

Comment: @Luis Thanks for the heads up on the Widcomm thing. I am not 100% sure we are using the Widcomm/Broadcom stack (see [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/972761/how-can-i-tell-which-bluetooth-stack-my-windows-computer-is-using)), that aside, on both systems the capabilities match the screenshots above which makes me think that I should just adapt the code to fail gracefully if the relevant capabilities are not present - also the client is currently deciding whether the functionality is worth the extra complication. It might be a while before I get the go ahead to test this out...